# Instantiating a class with "!" in Swift?

Tags: swift, class, instantiation

I recently came across someone creating an instance of a class like this:

```
var myModel: MyModel!
```

I have not seen this before.  Can someone please explain the difference between the above and the more familiar instantiation:

```
var myModel = MyModel()
```

Comment: `MyModel!` does *not* create an instance. It's a type annotation that tells the compiler (dangerously) that `MyModel` will explicitly not be `nil` (although it may, in fact, be)

Comment: @jnpdx no it doesn't

Comment: It is called 'Implicitely Unrwapped Optional Property'. It means that it can be nil but can be accessed without unwrapping its optional value.

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ID53